# Valid Braces - CodeWars Challenge

Tags: javascript, string, curly-braces, braces

There is a [challenge on codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/valid-braces/train/javascript) that asks you to check whether a string of parentheses, brackets, and curly braces is valid.

> A string of braces is considered valid if all braces are matched with the correct brace.

I.e. `"()"` is valid and `"[(])"` is not.

`"(){}[]"` is valid and `"[({})](]"` is not. Etc.

I've been able to create some logic to check for whether or not there are the right number of opening and closing braces.

**ATTEMPT**:

```
function validBraces(braces) {

  let parenCount = 0;
  let squareBracketCount = 0;
  let curlyBraceCount = 0;

    for (let i =0; i < braces.length; i++) {
      let character = braces[i];
        if (character === "(") {
          parenCount -= 1;
          }
        if (character === ")") {
          parenCount += 1;
          }
        if (character === "[") {
          squareBracketCount -= 1;
          }
        if (character === "]") {
          squareBracketCount += 1;
        }
        if (character === "{") {
          curlyBraceCount -= 1;
        }
        if (character === "}") {
          curlyBraceCount += 1;
        }
      }
      if (parenCount === 0 && squareBracketCount === 0 && curlyBraceCount === 0) {
        return true;
      } 
      else {
        return false;
      }
}
```

But I've not been able to come up with a way to check for whether or not the opening brace "closes" before the next *type* of brace opens.

Maybe something like this?

```
if (
  (firstChar === "(" && lastChar === ")") ||
  (firstChar === "{" && lastChar === "}") ||
  (firstChar === "[" && lastChar === "]")
) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

But then this would have to be checked in accordance with my other `if-statement`...(?)

**EDIT**: Key to understanding this challenge is that the closing brace must either come directly after the opening brace or it must be "parallel"  - in symmetry with the other.

Comment: Just a hint, you'll need to keep track of when you enter a brace and when you exit the proper brace.

Comment: As @ChaosPandion says, you may want to push each opening brace onto a stack and check that each closing brace matches the most recent opener before popping it off the stack. If the closing brace doesn't match, return false. At the end of the string the stack should have length zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `array` to keep track of previously appeared opening braces and once any closing tag  appears you need to match it with the last value of array if it's matching pop the last value out of else else return false, in the end if you're left with empty array return true else return false

```js
function validBraces(braces){
  let tracer = []
  for(let i=0;i < braces.length; i++){
    if ( braces[i] === "(" || braces[i] === "{" || braces[i] === "["){
      tracer.push(braces[i])
    } else{
      if(tracer.length === 0) return false
      let lastValue = tracer[tracer.length-1]
      if( (braces[i] === ']' && lastValue === '[') || (braces[i] === '}' && lastValue === '{') || (braces[i] === ')' && lastValue === '('))
      {
        tracer.pop()
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return tracer.length === 0
}


console.log(validBraces( "()" )) // true
console.log(validBraces( "[]" )) // true
console.log(validBraces( "{}" )) // true
console.log(validBraces( "(){}[]" )) // true
console.log(validBraces( "([{}])" )) // true
console.log(validBraces( "(}" )) // false
console.log(validBraces( "[(])" )) // false
console.log(validBraces( "({})[({})]" )) // true
console.log(validBraces( "(})" )) // false
console.log(validBraces( "(({{[[]]}}))" )) //true
console.log(validBraces( "{}({})[]" )) // true
console.log(validBraces( ")(}{][" )) // false
console.log(validBraces( "())({}}{()][][" )) // false
console.log(validBraces( "(((({{" ))  // false
console.log(validBraces( "}}]]))}])" )) // false
```

Comment: Hello can you please explain why you have `return tracer.length === 0;` and what that is doing, exactly? What is the difference between that and `if (tracer.length === 0) return true;`?

Comment: I see now that, in fact, there is no difference between `return tracer.length === 0;` and `if (tracer.length === 0) {return true}; else {return false};` - `return tracer.length === 0;` returns a boolean.

Comment: @HappyHands31 `===` ( equality operator ) always evaluates to a Boolean value, so depending on length it will return a Boolean value

Answer (score 9):

You don't really need to use arrays here, you can just use regex and recursion:

```js
const regex = /\(\)|\[\]|\{\}/;
const validBraces = braces => regex.test(braces)
  ? validBraces(braces.replace(regex, ''))
  : '' === braces

console.log(validBraces('{{}}')) // true
console.log(validBraces('{{[]}}')) // true
console.log(validBraces('{[{}]}')) // true
console.log(validBraces('({{}})')) // true
console.log(validBraces('{[()]}')) // true
console.log(validBraces('{{}[}')) // false
console.log(validBraces('{{]}}')) // false
console.log(validBraces('{}}')) // false
console.log(validBraces('{({}}')) // false
console.log(validBraces('((}}')) // false
console.log(validBraces('}[)}')) // false
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function validBraces(braces){
 while(/\(\)|\[\]|\{\}/g.test(braces)){braces = braces.replace(/\(\)|\[\]|\{\}/g,"")}
 return !braces.length;
}

// double regex
```

Answer (score 2):

In scala you can do this

```
object Kata {

  def validBraces(s: String): Boolean =
    s.replace("()", "").replace("[]", "").replace("{}", "") match { case "" => true; case `s` => false; case x => validBraces(x) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My JavaScript solution of this kata is simple to understand and passes all tests. Yet im aware its optimization isn't top-notch. It simply eliminates elements step by step:

1. **Start:** ( { [] } ) || ( { [] } }
2. **Then:** ( {} ) || ( {} }
3. **Then:** () || (}
   **Finish:** clear || leftovers
4. When length = 0 it passes, and when length > 0 it wont

```js
   function validBraces(braces){
while(braces.indexOf("{}") !== -1 || braces.indexOf("()") !== -1 || braces.indexOf("[]") !== -1){
    braces = braces.replace("{}", "").replace("()", "").replace("[]", "");
}
return braces.length === 0 ? true: false;

console.log(validBraces("(({{[[]]}}))"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in Scala with some tests and it works. In case the string's length is 2 if dont need to enter the recursive call because in the match you have already checked if it correct or not :

```
   object Kata1{
        def validBraces(s: String): Boolean ={
          var valid: Boolean = true
          if(s.length > 1){
           s(0) match{
              case '('  => if( s(1) == ')' || s(s.length-1) == ')'){
                if(s.length != 2){
                  if(s(1) == ')'){
                    valid = validBraces(s.substring(2, s.length))
                  }else{
                    valid = validBraces(s.substring(1, s.length-1))
                  }
                }
          } else {
                if(s.lastIndexOf(')') != -1){
                 var newS = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(')')).concat(s.substring(s.indexOf(')')+1, s.length))
                  valid = validBraces(newS.substring(1, s.length-1))
                }else valid = false
           }
        case '['  => if( s(1) == ']' || s(s.length-1) == ']') {
         if(s.length != 2){
          if(s(1) == ']'){
           valid = validBraces(s.substring(2, s.length))
         }else{
           valid = validBraces(s.substring(1, s.length-1))
         }
       }
      } else {
       if(s.lastIndexOf(']') != -1){
         var newS = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(']')).concat(s.substring(s.indexOf(']')+1, s.length))
        valid = validBraces(newS.substring(1, s.length-1))
      }else valid = false
    }
    case '{'  => if( s(1) == '}' || s(s.length-1) == '}') {
      if(s.length != 2){
        if(s(1) == '}'){
          valid = validBraces(s.substring(2, s.length))
        }else{
          valid = validBraces(s.substring(1, s.length-1))
        }
      }
    } else {
      if(s.lastIndexOf('}') != -1){
        var newS = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('}')).concat(s.substring(s.indexOf('}')+1, s.length))
        valid = validBraces(newS.substring(1, s.length-1))
      }else valid = false
    }
    case _ => valid = false
  }
  /*if(s.length != 2 && valid){
    if(s(1) == ')'  || s(1) == '}'  || s(1) == ']' ){
      valid = validBraces(s.substring(2, s.length))
    }else{
      valid = validBraces(s.substring(1, s.length-1))
    }
  }*/
}else{
  valid = false
}

if(s.length == 0){
  valid = true
}
valid
 }
 }

 Kata1.validBraces("()") //true
 Kata1.validBraces("[()]") //true
 Kata1.validBraces("[(])") //false
 Kata1.validBraces("([{}])") //true
 Kata1.validBraces("([{]})") //false
 Kata1.validBraces("{({{()}({}())})}")//true
 Kata1.validBraces("({]}{")//false
```