# Why would I use a stack-based solution?

Tags: javascript, stack

**TL:DR = What are some use cases for stack-based solutions?**

I'm making my way through CodeWars, and today I ran into a problem called [*Valid Braces*](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5277c8a221e209d3f6000b56). Of the answers there were two prominent ways people solved the problem: either with regex or with a stack(?). I tried both, but I didn't understand the purpose of the latter. The regex solution (to me) is less dense and legible, so that's what I originally went with.

```
const validBraces = (braces) => {
  const regExp = /\(\)|\[\]|\{\}/g;

  return (
      regExp.test(braces)
        ? validBraces(braces.replace(regExp, ''))
        : '' === braces
    )
}
```

credit: [Mike K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60002761/13408555)

This was the first time I saw the use of a stack to check values, and I really haven't found a good way of thinking about it.

```
const validBraces = (braces) => {
  const pairs = { '(':')', '[':']', '{':'}' };
  const stack = [];

  for (const brace of braces) {
    if( pairs[brace] ) {
      stack.push(brace)
    } else {
      if (brace !== pairs[stack.pop()]) {return false}
    }
  }

  return stack.length === 0;
}
```

Either way, my question is why would I use one over the other, and what are some of the uses of the stack-based paradigm?

Comment: I think the stack solution is actually pretty clever. It basically checks that any time you encounter a right (closing) brace, you ensure that the last left (opening) brace was of the same type. i.e. `[` matches `]`, `(` matches `)` etc. A stack is a good solution because the last brace (aka the "top" of the stack) is the only one you care about making sure it matches. If it matches, you remove it (`stack.pop()`) and you proceed, if it doesn't match, return false saying the brace configuration is not valid

Comment: "*what are some of the uses of the stack-based paradigm?*" To...solve this problem? A stack is also a classic data structure and at the basis of many existing algorithms. A depth-first search is implemented using a stack and a breadth first search uses the same algorithm but a queue instead. I guess you could eschew the use of a stack. It would make about as much sense as a builder deciding not to nails because there are other ways of joining two things together.